# .env file to use process.env in JS, Node.js and MySQL sn't working - seems to be the .env file as when putting info direct in JS it works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, mysql-connector

I'm new to Mysql and I am trying to write a program that will let me use js to manipulate the data in it.  I am following a tutorial and have done exactly what iot says but for some reason when I make the env file, it stops working. I have written out eveything as the tutorial states, but when I come to run it I get this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND '127.0.0.1',
    at PromisePool.query (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Database practise\database mySQL-node.js practise\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:356:22)
    at getAllnotes (file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Database%20practise/database%20mySQL-node.js%20practise/database.js:16:31)
    at file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Database%20practise/database%20mySQL-node.js%20practise/database.js:20:23
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12) {
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: -3008,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
```

I was hoping that it would show the data that I had but is just coming up with the error above.

It definitely looks like the .env file as when I put all the info direct into js (host, user etc) it works fine, but for some reason it doesn't work when I transfer all the info to the env file.

This is the JS file

```
import mysql from "mysql2"
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()



const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE
}).promise()


async function getAllnotes() {
    const [rows] = await pool.query("SELECT * from notes")
    return rows
  }
  
  const notes = await getAllnotes()
  console.log(notes)
```

this is the .env file

```
MYSQL_HOST = '127.0.0.1',
MYSQL_USER = 'root'
MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'password',
MYSQL_DATABASE ='notes_app'
```

and the package.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "name": "admin",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

the tutorial if you want to see it is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hej48pi_lOc and the part I'm stuck on is at 9.50.

Ive installed dotenv & mysql2, but still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out.  Its the commas and spaces in the env file which i've deleted and it's now working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).